# How delete same value in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete same value in topic field and keep first row of value.

such as

```
no topic 

1  1234 

2  1234 

3  1234
```

no = autoincrement

output

```
no topic

1  1234
```

---

This my code

```
$sql ="DELETE FROM data
WHERE no IN (SELECT * 
             FROM (SELECT no FROM data
                   GROUP BY topic HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
                  ) AS A
             )";
```

This code delete first value but I want to delete all same value and keep first value like example.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DELETE FROM data
WHERE no NOT IN (SELECT no FROM
                   (SELECT MIN(no) as no,topic FROM data
                    GROUP BY topic
                   )NotDelete
                );
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a928/1)

Comment: Thank you very much this code work for me.